# Very light golden hazy beer with citrus flavour

Tags: beer, beer-styles, wheat-beer, beersmith

It is my first home brew. The batch size was 10ltr. I used 100% wheat malt of 2 kgs and used bitter orange peel of 36gm instead of Hop. The OG was1.02 and FG is 1.01 after 14 days of fermentation using Safale S04 of 11.5g at 25 - 27°C. After 14 days though it taste like flat beer but the colour is very light golden and it taste too much citrusy... 
I have attached an image of it
Kindly suggest what may go wrong...

[image: Very light golden hazy beer with citrus flavour]

Comment: First off that bottle will not hold pressure. You need to use a beer bottle with a crown cap or a swing top that are built to hold pressure. I'm sure all your co2 escaped around that cork. Also, did you use sugar to "prime" it so it will create co2 in the bottle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As farmersteve said that bottle isn't going to work for carbonating. You need a bottle that will be air tight, and to add a priming sugar.

Cloudy is to be expected from 100% wheat.

About the citrus balance, I think the 1.24oz / 36gm of peel was fine. And the amount of grain was good. You just had poor effenciency.

Your OG is about half what it should have been with that recipe I get a target OG of 1.044 at 75 % efficiency with the volumes and weights you provided. So it's going to *basically* have half of the other attributes of the malt too, which is why the citrus is over bearing.

Maybe if you can update with the exact kind of wheat you used and your brew process we can help with the efficiency problem.

Comment: The wheat used is an Indian Medium Hard Bread Wheat called Lokwan B.... Which had been soaked in water for 12 hrs then sprouted for 3 days and dried in sun for 4 days... Then crushed to malt... But unfortunately I have kept the malt for a month... Then I used it for brewing...

Comment: @RajarsheeMajumdar wow you malted your own grain, that's awsome! Malting grain is not an easy process, this would explain most of the effenciency issue.

Comment: To me I feel these are really easy out in India.... But getting the end product is quite tough... I'm not sure about my beer...

Comment: @RajarsheeMajumdar unfortunately I don't think there's a way to fix the balance issue of the citrus, aside from blending with more beer. The carbonation can be though, by adding priming sugar and bottling in sealed bottles. Also in malting, the germination is terminated just before the sprout comes out. If allowed to sprout too much it may have used most of the sugars to do so.

Comment: Thanks buddy for your suggestions... Firstly I just want to understand whether my process and the ingredients were right... and the photo that I have uploaded does it looks like beer... If there are any necessary changes I need to adept kindly suggest... I'm ready to try it again with 50% wheat and 50% barley...

Comment: @RajarsheeMajumdar you would do better using commercially malted grains for your first brew, Your recipe and weights look good even with using peel instead of hops. If you were to dialing in the malting process more I think youre on your way to a good brew.

Comment: Got that.... And if I use 1 Oz magnum hop next time will 20 LTR batch of 50% barlye and wheat... Will that do....

Comment: I've malted wheat and it's pretty easy and it worked fine in my beer, but I never did 100% wheat malt. If you can get barley, then that will help out significantly. Doing a Brew In A Bag and crushing the malt very fine will also help with wheat malt. Also, if you want a clear beer, you could add gelatin after fermentation. Whirloc also helps clarify the beer.

Comment: @RajarsheeMajumdar yes that would be a great recipe to do.

Comment: Hi... Just to recheak ... Is forming a layer of forth while carbonating is normal or there is any problem....

Comment: @RajarsheeMajumdar "froth" or foam is an issue if it's in the bottles. Sounds like the yeast has hit krausen again either from New sugars or new yeast that's able to eat the last of that 1.010 gravity. Get it all back in the fermentor or open those bottles, they may burst.

Comment: Thanks.... I will do the same but tell me one thing is carbonation happening and will the beer be drinkable after 7 days...

Comment: @RajarsheeMajumdar it's hard to tell. If we're talking about the bottle. In the picture, and it has say 1inch of foam it's doing more than just carbonating / bottle conditioning. If it's just a thin layer of clean foam with nothing brown on the bubbles it may be ok, since there's a lot of head space there and the cork wouldn't be air tight. Put then in a safe place in case those bottles start to explode. If you want to just wait and see.

Comment: Thanks buddy ... It's just a thin layer of white foam and no brownish in it.. and I have stored the whole lot in plastic bottles with lot of head space... What you suggest...

Comment: Thanks buddy ... It's just a thin layer of white foam and no brownish in it.. and I have stored the whole lot in plastic bottles with lot of head space... What you suggest...

Comment: @RajarsheeMajumdar plastic is good. I would minimise the head space to 3/4 inch, in a bottle.

Comment: I have kept more than that.... Buddy can I have your mail id so that I can be in touch with you...

Comment: @RajarsheeMajumdar minimising it head space will help it carbonate more and reduce oxygen exposure. I don't know if any way to get you my contact info privately. I'm evilzymurgist in instagram, Twitter and untapped we can message there.